# Is there a way to export enums with ES6 settings in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

In using Typescript, I was attempting to export an enum into another file using ES6 import / export statements like so:

```
export enum EnumerableThing {
  green,
  red,
  blue
}
```

However, when I tried to import that statement with `import { EnumerableThing } from './enum'` it wasn't detected and didn't affect the resulting Javascript code.

Is there a reason why this is / how to fix it?

To note, I have ES6 import statements in my tsconfig. I realize that interfaces also doesn't actually compile Javascript code, *however*, interfaces are exportable despite not being compiled into Javascript themselves.

Edit, here is my tsconfig file

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "allowJs": true
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Thanks you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "*it wasn't detected and didn't affect the resulting Javascript code*"? What did it transpile to? What did you expect?

Comment: Can you also add your `tsconfig.json` to your question?

Comment: What you're doing seems fine, but there's some details missing. What error message do you get? What file is `EnumerableThing` in? What file are you importing from?

Comment: all-of-the-above + post any compile errors you might have.

Comment: It doesn't emit any compilation errrors.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually use the import, it will not appear in the generated JS. If you refer to the *value* `EnumerableThing`, e.g. `let x = EnumerableThing.green`, the import will be retained.

Comment: The file is actually being imported and used. To clarify, the enum is declared and exported, then imported into another file and used in that file.

Comment: Please post the usage code and the emitted JS for that file